# Visual Studio Reference Not Being Copied Over In Multiple Project Environment

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference

I have a solution file in VS 2010 and it has multiple projects in it.

Now, I have a reference to this dll call MySql.Data.Entity.dll.

As an example, I have the following projects setup in the solution:

- Domain (reference to MySql.Data.Entity.dll)
- Domain.Test (reference to the project "Domain")

I want that Domain.Test to copy over all the references from Domain, so I set the Property on that dll to "Copy Local - True". It did not copy over to the Domain.Test project.

I have encounter this problem from before with over dlls. What I did was this:

```
namespace Domain.Helpers
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// To trick VS to deploy required assemblies
        /// </summary>
        class BuildTricker
        {
            public void AssemblyTricker()
            {
                new LinFu.DynamicProxy.CallAdapter(null);
                new NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactory();
            }
        }
    }
```

And worked fine. If I "use" the class it will know to copy it over to "Domain.Test".

Problem with this is that there is nothing I can initialize/"use" from this MySql.Data.Entity.dll.

Note: Just adding the namespace in a Using statement won't do the trick, you HAVE TO "use" a class in the dll for it to be copied over.

I am currently manually referencing this dll into all the projects that requires it.

So, my question is. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Or is this a VS limitation?

Thanks,

Chi

Answer (score 1):

That's the catch with COMReferences, they're not resources, so they don't get copied.

By setting the reference to MySql.Data.Entity.dll's `Isolated` property to True, the file is copied over from its original location to your "Domain" project's bin folder and finally to your "Domain.Test" project's bin folder.

Comment: What Isolated property? It only seems to exist for COMReferences